# Unable to use Anko Intent inside RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have context passed as an argument in the adapter of Recyclerview and hence as per the documentation of Anko, I should be able to start activity as shown below:

```
startActivity(intentFor<DetailActivity>())
```

I am writing this code in OnClickListener of an item inside onBindViewHolder method of RecyclerView Adapter. But, I am getting an error **unable to resolve startActivity(intentFor())**

I have already added the Anko commons dependency inside the gradle file. I am already using **context.startActivity(intentFor())**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the context for that.

```
context.startActivity(intentFor<DetailActivity>())
```

**UPDATE**

```
context.startActivity(context.intentFor<DetailActivity>())
```

Comment: oh...sloppy mistake!